# Vue vuetify datatable dynamic cell loading

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="records"
    :items-per-page="5"
    show-select
    loading
    item-key="id"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <div>
        <table-tabs></table-tabs>
        <v-text-field
          append-icon="mdi-close"
          class="mx-4"
          flat
          hide-details
          label="Search"
          prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
          solo-inverted
        ></v-text-field>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
      <product-instance-cell v-bind:item="item" :data="item"></product-instance-cell>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.boxCode="{ item }">
      <serial-cell v-bind:boxCode="item.boxCode" :serial="item.boxCode"></serial-cell>
    </template>
    <template v-if="hasField('manager')" v-slot:item.manager="{ item }">
      <user-cell v-bind:user="item.manager" :user="item.manager"></user-cell>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.customer="{ item }">
      <customer-cell v-bind:customer="item.customer" :customer="item.customer"></customer-cell>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.updatedAt="{ item }">
      <date-cell v-bind:updatedAt="item.updatedAt" :date="item.updatedAt"></date-cell>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

like below i have to pass field's name and cell componenet directly under template to draw custom cell for specific model & field.

```
   <template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
      <product-instance-cell v-bind:item="item" :data="item"></product-instance-cell>
    </template>
```

but what i insist to do is, dynamically loading the cells because my table does not have specific usage model. the table can draw 5 different types of model `Array<T>` and i have something called `table spec` which contains all the information required to draw the table. e.g.
header cell names, sorting logics, max row count, cell component names by model <-> field name, etc..

It was easy to deal with data table header which does not requires another template, and also the full template code above works. but for only one model. i'd like to create super dynamic table with spec data. how to achieve this?

not specific solution for this case, but other vue's philosophical approaches are welcome.

Comment: It's better to have separate code for each model, or else you will have to contemplate too many exceptions, and your code can become a frankenstein

Comment: @ariel I understand, but yet i had pre-defined all the regulations & action required by each model. so i really would like to make the table abstract and oop based

Answer (score 0):

I've worked today on a similar problem, making a very Dynamic table that renders different for each model but that has some columns, aka, `v-slot:item.<name>` in common.

I have a common headers json object that has all the properties the table should render for each model, it looks something like this:

```js
"headers": [
    { "text" : "Data / Hora" ,       "value" : "date" ,             "filterable" : true ,   "sortable" : true ,     "type" : "text-date" , "align" : "left" , "format" : "AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM" },
    { "text" : "Tipus pujada" ,      "value" : "upload_type" ,      "filterable" : true ,   "sortable" : false ,    "type" : "text"      , "align" : "center"    },
    { "text" : "Elements" ,          "value" : "elements" ,         "filterable" : true ,   "sortable" : false ,    "type" : "text"  },
    { "text" : "Rebut i validat" ,   "value" : "status" ,           "filterable" : true ,   "sortable" : false ,    "type" : "chip" ,   "style": [ { "color" : "red", "value" : "ERROR" } , { "color" : "green" , "value" : "OK" } ] },
    { "text" : "Log" ,               "value" : "log" ,              "filterable" : false ,  "sortable" : false ,    "type" : "icon" ,   "icon": "mdi-magnify" , "event" : "click" , "action" : "openDialog" },
    { "text" : "Fitxer pujat" ,      "value" : "uploaded_file" ,    "filterable" : false ,  "sortable" : false ,    "type" : "icon" ,   "icon": "mdi-file" , "event" : "click" , "action" : "downloadJSONFileFromJSONData", "url" : "xxxxxxxx", "filename" : "AAAA-MM-DD-filename.json" }
]
```

So I can render all the columns that have the same header type like `icon` or `text`, `chip` whatever as if they where the same.

To solve make it work without naming specifically for each header I've used computed properties that can filter the header slots by its types:

```js
computed: {
  computedHeaders: function () {
    //Filters the headers of type Icon
    return this.headers.filter(header => header.type==='icon');
  }
}
```

so I can render all the slots that have something in common but different naming:

```js
<template v-for="(head,i) in computedHeaders" v-slot:[`item.${head.value}`]="{ item }">
 <v-icon
    :key="i"
    v-text="head.icon"
  >
  </v-icon>
</template>
```